# Are std::stack and std::queue cache friendly?

Tags: c++

Do std::stack and std::queue allocate their data in contiguous memory, so they are considered "cache-friendly"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::stack` and `std::queue` are container adapters, a strange beast that provides a stripped down uniform interface on a compile time determined container.

By default, they use `std::deque` as their backing store, which is not all that cache friendly (in every implementation I have examined).

`stack` can easily be handed a `vector`, which makes it friendly to the cache.

Making `queue` use a `vector` is tricky.  You either have to wrap the `vector` into a circular buffer, or make it a double-ended vector.  Both of those are non-trivial.

The only cache-friendly adaptive-size container in std is vector (and its near clone string), so there you go.

Comment: `std::array` is a container. And `std::string` is mostly a container ;)

Answer (score 1):

`std::stack` and `std::queue` are container adapters, They are based on the underlaying conteiner that can be for example `std::vector` and in this case they will be as you are saying "cache-friendly" or `std::list` and in this case they will not be "cache-friendly".

By default the both container adapters use `std::deque` as the underlaying container because it has all necessary methods to simulate the adapters.
For example `std::vector` does not have required method `pop_front` and can not be used as an underlaying container for `std::queue`.

You can define your own underlaying container. The requirements are described in the C++ Standard.